# Remove divs from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to remove a html div in objective-C/xCode? So for example the html looks like this :

```
<html>
  <div id="menu"> the menu code </div>
  <p> lorem ipsum text </p>
</html>
```

So if I could remove this menu only the text content would be displayed. That is what I want to make.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use javascript to hide it in the webView delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"menu\").style.display='none';"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
}
```

Comment: I put it in de ViewController.m which contains the webview but it doesn't seem to get called. I'm very new to iOS where can I find the webView delegate method?

Comment: I missed this : `self.webView.delegate = self;`

Comment: Yes you have to set yourself as delegate of the webView programmatically `self.webView.delegate = self;` or using the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Swift coders can remove elements by id as follow (I used this to remove twitter OAuth's cancel button):

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
      self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById(\"cancel\").style.display='none';")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute a JavaScript expression in the web view, example from one of my projects:

```
NSString *jsLoadSudoku = [NSString stringWithFormat:JAVASCRIPT_LOADSUDOKU, jsonString];
[[self webView] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsLoadSudoku];
```

Just pass in a JavaScript expression that removes the div element.